# Not able to post in my facebook wall using java

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, facebook-oauth, restfb

I am trying to post a message on my facebook wall using Java. I have marked all the permissions. But I am getting the exception "FacebookOAuthException". Kindly help in resolving this. Thanks in advance!

```
package com.java.sample.workouts;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient;
import com.restfb.FacebookClient;
import com.restfb.Parameter;
import com.restfb.Version;
import com.restfb.types.FacebookType;
import com.restfb.types.User;
import com.sun.media.jfxmedia.logging.Logger;

public class PostInFBWall {

    public static void updateStatus(String message) {
        FacebookClient facebookClient= new DefaultFacebookClient("access token", Version.LATEST);
         facebookClient.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class,
                 com.restfb.Parameter.with("message", message));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PostInFBWall.updateStatus("FB testing");
    }
}
```

And the screenshot of facebook permission is:

[image: Facebook permissions]

And the exception in eclipse is:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
      either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages \
      and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
      requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with \
      sufficient administrative permission (code 200, subcode null)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1199)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1116)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:1057)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:979)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:453)
at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.publish(DefaultFacebookClient.java:478)
at com.java.sample.workouts.PostInFBWall.updateStatus(PostInFBWall.java:35)
at com.java.sample.workouts.PostInFBWall.main(PostInFBWall.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

Publishing messages or photos to your user wall is not possible anymore, the required permission would have been `publish_actions`, but it is deprecated.